# How to add bullet points and product SKU to product title in array list

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom product page for WooCommerce that displays a list of products under their respective category headings. You can view the page here: https://libertymachinery.com/inventory/

I need to do two things with the product list:

1. Add bullet points in front of each product title
2. Add the product SKU to the end of each product title (For example, "Citizen M32 CNC Swiss Screw Machine (#47623)

Since this isn't the shop page, I'm not sure how to call the SKU where I need it to appear. I don't mind displaying the SKU on the end of the product title everywhere, but I don't want to add it to the actual title in each post.

I was able to add bullet points to the category headings, but couldn't figure out how to also add them to the product titles. Here is the code I'm using for that section of the page.

```
        <!-- section -->
        <section>
        <?php       
        $args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => "product_cat",
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true/* ,
    'include'    => $ids */
);
$product_categories = get_terms($args);

foreach($product_categories as $product_category){
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'orderby'    => 'title',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'tax_query' => array(
              'relation' => 'AND',
               array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                   'field' => 'slug',
                   'terms' => $product_category->slug
                )
           ),
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($product_category->count > 0){


        $count_h = 0;
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            global $product;
            $count_h ++;

            if($product->catalog_visibility == 'visible'){      
                if($count_h == 1){
        echo "<br><a href='".get_category_link($product_category->term_id)."'><strong style='text-transform: uppercase;'><li>".$product_category->name.'</li></strong></a><br>';
                }

                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br />';
            } 

        endwhile; 
    }
    wp_reset_query();
 }
```

Comment: We'll need a bit more info than this.
What does the table look like?